# In Eldritch Horror, when a mythos card refers to a monster's toughness, does it mean its current or max toughness?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The Blood Flows mythos card says under its event:

> The Lead Investigator discards 1 Monster of his choice and loses Health equal to its toughness

Do I use the monster's current or max health?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toughness is the max health. That's the damage you should take. 
To clarify,  a monster taking damage does not effect its toughness. Once a monster takes damage equal to Toughness,  it dies

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question, which was regarding whether mention of a monster's toughness pertained to its current health or max health, not simply how a monster dies.

Comment: I thought it was implied.  Toughness always refers to its max health.  I will clarify

Comment: Is there any reference where they indicate the other case saying 'a monster's current health' or any other reference supporting this? Maybe they use the term toughness always in the context of a static max value in conjuction with talking of 'damage'? I'm not sure and will look closer at wording too.

Comment: I doubt there is a specific ruling for this in the actual rule book. Based on the wording, toughness would refer to the printed toughness or the current toughness based on effects that increase a monsters toughness. 

Taking damage does not decrease toughness. They die from taking damage equal to their toughness. I'm basing my answer on that understanding

Comment: "The Monster loses Health equal to the number of successes rolled. Indicate this by placing Health tokens on the Monster token. When a Monster has lost Health equal to or greater than its toughness, the Monster is defeated and returned to the Monster cup." Doesn't specifically state this but backs you up IMO (p15 rulebook).  If toughness changed when the monster was damaged then 5 toughness monsters would die after 3 damage:P  But it's pretty clear to me you're adding damage tokens not removing toughness.  PS: Picture of toughness on p14 of the rulebook.

Comment: I guess you've also shown that if they wanted something equal to how much the monster had left, they would have said 'the monster's health'.

Answer (score -1):

The 'current toughness' and 'max toughness' are the same thing.

The damage done doesn't reduce the monster toughness.